# Trying to mock Laravel Socialite Google Login for integration testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-socialite

I am trying to mock Laravel Socialite to test Google oAUTH Login using the guide [here](https://stefanzweifel.io/posts/how-i-write-integration-tests-for-laravel-socialite-powered-apps/).

```php
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\GoogleProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User as SocialUser;

public function mock_socialite ($email = 'foo@gmail.com', $token = 'foo', $id = 1)
    {
        // create a mock user
        $socialiteUser = $this->createMock(SocialUser::class);
        $socialiteUser->token = $token;
        $socialiteUser->id = $id;
        $socialiteUser->email = $email;

        // create a mock provider of the user
        $provider = $this->createMock(GoogleProvider::class);
        $provider->expects($this->any())
            ->method('user')
            ->willReturn($socialiteUser);

        // create a mock Socialite instance
        $stub = $this->createMock(Socialite::class);
        $stub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('driver')
            //->with('google')
            ->willReturn($provider);

        // Replace Socialite Instance with our mock
        $this->app->instance(Socialite::class, $stub);
    }
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
Trying to configure method "driver" which cannot be configured 
because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

I checked and found that `driver()` method does exist in `Illuminate\Support\Manager` (from where `Socialite` is extended) and this method is a public method. Not sure why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socialite is a facade and often their integration is far away from how you would use it, therefor it does not have the driver method. You are including that facade to mock it, this is not the approach he has in the guide. So replacing the facade with the use statement he uses, would probably solved your problems.

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
```

Instead of.

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Let me try this and update you.

Comment: No, it is still not working. Now it complains with `Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\InvalidStateException`

Comment: But there is nothing in your code that references that?

Comment: I guess this is not you binding the socialiate mock correctly can i see the controler / logic you are calling with these mocks

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was calling `Socialite::buildProvider()` directly in my controller whereas I was binding the mock to `driver` method.